# Reading child nodes with multiple namespaces

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath, namespaces

There are many many posts about namespaces and reading XML nodes but I have been unable to find an answer to my specific query. I believe my approach is correct but I am obviously missing something that is preventing it from working.

Overview - I am making a web service call which returns XML which I need to clean up and dynamically create and populate a datatable. To clean up I am trying to read the nodes I need from the returned XML which contains multiple namespaces.

I can get data out of the document but not at the level I want. I want the XMLContent nodelist to contain data at the "Container" level.

The comments in the code show the line that gives me data but not at the required level and the line which I expected to return the next level down but it doesn't return anything. I appreciate to get what I need I will need to step down another level but this is the point where the nodelist returns null.

I can't just load the XML into a dataset or datatable without first manipulating it.

Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="namespaceone" xmlns:xsi="namespacetwo" xmlns:xsd="namespacethree">
    <soap:Body>
        <Response xmlns="http://namespacefour">
            <Result>
                <Data xmlns="http://namespacefive" xmlns:t="http://namespacesix">
                    <Container>
                        <Properties>
                            <Property1>a</Property1>
                            <Property2>b</Property2>
                        </Properties>
                    </Container>
                    <Container>
                        <Properties>
                            <Property1>c</Property1>
                            <Property2>d</Property2>
                        </Properties>
                    </Container>
                </Data>
            </Result>
        </Response>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

```vb
        Dim XMLdoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
        XMLdoc.LoadXml(strXML)

        Dim XMLContent As XmlNodeList

        Dim nsMgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(XMLdoc.NameTable())
        ns.AddNamespace("dflt", XMLdoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
        ns.AddNamespace("ns1", XMLdoc.DocumentElement.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("soap"))
        ns.AddNamespace("ns2", "http://namespacetwo")
        ns.AddNamespace("ns3", "http://namespacethree")
        ns.AddNamespace("ns4", "http://namespacefour")
        ns.AddNamespace("ns5", "http://namespacefive")
        ns.AddNamespace("ns6", "http://namespacesix")

        'This returns content but not at the level I want
        XMLContent = XMLdoc.SelectNodes("/ns1:Envelope/ns1:Body/ns4:Response/ns4:Result", nsMgr)

        'This does not return anything
        XMLContent = XMLdoc.SelectNodes("/ns1:Envelope/ns1:Body/ns4:Response/ns4:Result/ns5:Data", nsMgr)

        If Not XMLContent Is Nothing Then
            For Each node As XmlNode In XMLContent
                'Create and populate table here
            Next node
        End If
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you please post a sample document you are running the XPATH on? And a general suggestion - try to make your query a bit more generic, so that it doesn't care abnout NSs, e.g. `//Response/Result/Data`

Comment: Agree with @t1gor's request for a sample document.  It should be added as text, ***not as an image***.

Comment: Fair point guys - changed the image to a code sample for the XML. Will investigate a more generic query.

Comment: I tried testing your code and the `<Data>` node is successfully selected by the second `SelectNodes()` call. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/zbdTZ6.  But there's one problem with your code -- you define a variable `Dim nsMgr As ...` but then you add the namespaces to something different named `ns`.  As such your code doesn't compile standalone, so I fixed it in the fiddle.  But maybe in your "real" code `ns` is actually defined and you're adding your namespaces to the wrong `XmlNamespaceManager`?

Comment: Thanks for responding dbc. The ns nsMgr is just my refactoring mistake - the code is in a test rig so I renamed some bits before posting and missed that. I don't understand. I see it working in fiddle which is exactly what I would expect given the higher level nodes match fine but the code in my testrig will not match on anything below that level. I will review again with focus on the namespaces. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way, but will work:

`//*[local-name(.) = 'Response']/*[local-name(.) = 'Result']/*[local-name(.) = 'Data']`

Also is NS-independant. [Testing link](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/5124053f54d13f4d4286f22812f2083f).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions guys but I have cracked it. Turns out the XML was encoded from the data node and below although the outer nodes were not encoded. I should have spotted that but didn't expect a mix of encoded and not. Anyway, if I run a HttpUtility.HtmlDecode on the web service output then the code I posted originally works fine.